# java.io.IOException: Object type not supported

Tags: codenameone

I am getting the below error when i am trying to save Image which user the uploaded.

```
java.io.IOException: Object type not supported: com.codename1.ui.Image value: com.codename1.ui.Image@76a29a7
at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Util.java:406)
```

Below is my program.

**User class**

```
public class User implements Externalizable {
        private String name;
        private Image proImg;

        public void externalize(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
            Util.writeUTF(getName(), out);
            Util.writeObject(getProImg(), out);

        }
        public void internalize(int version, DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
            setName(Util.readUTF(in));
            setProImg((Image) Util.readObject(in));
        }
       ...

}
```

**StateMachine class**

```
 protected void onCreateAccountGui_SaveBtnAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    User usr =  new User();     
    usr.setName(findNametxta(c).getText());
    usr.setProImg(findProImgGallery(c).getImage());

    try
    {
        storedUser.writeObject("userStore", usr);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` is not an `Externalizable` class since it contains platform specific native image data and not bytes.

`EncodedImage` is `Externalizable`, so you should use that. By default all images we create (e.g. resources) are `EncodedImage` but if you have an `Image` or mutable image you can convert it to `EncodedImage` using:

```
EncodedImage enc = EncodedImage.createFromImage(img, jpgOrPng);
```